# What is the best way to update html continuously without the Maximum call stack size error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple text-based game for a friend's website. I need to be able to change an HTML element or update the HTML page without running into the Maximum call stack exceeded error. I'm currently using

```
document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "whatever"
```

and I need a method without the error

This is the first function that loads. It then goes off to the prompt_input(); function.

```
function title_screen(){
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
    quests.push('Getting Started');
    prompt_input();
}
```

This is the prompt input function.
It takes the user input at runs the appropriate function.
Every function except the restart(); function leads back to prompt_input(); to get the next round of player input.

```
function prompt_input(){
    var action = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    if (action == ""){
        prompt_input();

    }
    else{  
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += action;
var acceptable_actions = [...];
    var acc_check = acceptable_actions.includes(action);
    if (action  == 'help'){
        instruction_menu();
    }
    else if (action == "play"){
        prompt_input();
    }
    else if (action == "y"){
        player_yes();
    }
    else if (action == "yes"){
        player_yes();
    }
    else if (action == 'n'){
        player_no();
    }
    else if (action == 'no'){
        player_no();
    }
    else if (action  == 'loc'){
        print_location();
        prompt_input();
    }
    else if (action  == 'location'){
        print_location();
        prompt_input();
    }
    else if (action == 'name'){
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
        prompt_input();
    }
    else if (action == 'look'){
        if (player_location == 'The Casino'){
            casino_look();
}
        else{
            player_look();
        }}
    else if (action == 'right'){
        player_right();
        }
    else if (action == 'left'){
        player_left();
    }
    else if (action  == 'restart'){
        restart_game();
    }
    else if (action  == 'items'){
        items_print();
        prompt_input();
        }
    else if (action  == 'read'){
        player_read();
        prompt_input();
        }
    else if (action  == 'play'){
        if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
            start_game();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
        }
        }
    else if (action  == 'evb'){
        hidden_prompt();
    }
    else if (action  == 'outside'){
        print_outside();
    }
    else if (action  == 'back'){
        if (items.includes('Emu') === true){
            if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_back();
            }
        }
        else if (items.includes('Clown Car') === true){
            if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_back();
            }
        }
        else if (items.includes('Sailboat') === true){
            if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_back();
            }
        }
        else if (characters.includes('KGB Platoon') === true){
            if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_back();
}
}
else if (characters.includes('KGB Horde') === true){
            if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_back();
}
}
else if (characters.includes('KGB Army') === true){
            if (player_location == 'Title Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_back();
}
}
}
    else if (action  == 'next'){
        if (items.includes('Emu') === true){
            if (player_location == 'End Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_next();
            }
        }
        else if (items.includes('Clown Car') === true){
            if (player_location == 'End Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
            }
            else{
                player_next();
            }
            }
        else if (characters.includes('KGB Horde') === true){
            if (player_location == 'End Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
        }
            else{
                player_next();
            }
    }
    else if (characters.includes('KGB Army') === true){
            if (player_location == 'End Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
        }
            else{
                player_next();
            }
    }
        else if (items.includes('Sailboat') === true){
            if (player_location == 'End Screen'){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += '...'
                prompt_input();
}
            else{
                player_next();
}}
}
    else if (action == 'balance'){
        print_balance();
}
    else if (action == 'bal'){
        print_balance();
    }
    else if (action == 'shop'){
        player_store();
    }
    else if (action == 'sell'){
        player_sell();
    }
    else if (action == 'store'){
        player_store();
}
    else if (action == 'buy'){
        player_buy();
}
    else if (action == 'boom'){
        boom();
}
    else if (action == 'military gun call'){
        military_gun_call();
}
    else if (action == 'mgc'){
        military_gun_call();
}
    else if (action == 'eat'){
        player_eat();
    }
    else if (action == 'oml'){
        omlette();
}
    else if (action == 'russia'){
        read_russia_book();
    }
    else if (action  == 'dev'){
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
        prompt_input();
}
    else if (action == 'hostage'){
        if (player_location == 'Milk Store'){
            if ('Gun' in  items === true){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
                 items.push("Stalin's Hair");
                 taken_items.push("Stalin's Hair");
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "You have aquired Stalin's Hair."
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += 'You have aquired Milk.'
                 items.push("Milk");
                 taken_items.push("Milk");
                prompt_accomplish[player_location] = true;
                 balance =  balance - .35;
                prompt2();
            }
            else if (death_survivability >= 1){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "You survived death this time, but your death survivability has decreased."
                 death_survivability =  death_survivability - 1;
                prompt_input();
}
            else{
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
                restart(30);
            }
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here"
}
}
    else if (action == 'produce'){
        if (player_location == 'Milk Store'){
            if (death_survivability >= 1){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "You survived death this time, but your death survivability has decreased."
                 death_survivability =  death_survivability - 1;
                prompt_input();
}
            else{
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
                restart(10);
            }
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here"
}
}

    else if (action == 'dairy'){
        if (player_location == 'Milk Store'){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_accomplish[player_location] == true;
             items.push("Milk");
             taken_items.push("Milk");
             balance =  balance - .35;
            prompt2();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here"
}
}
    else if (action == 'quests'){
        quest_print();
        prompt_input();
}

    else if (action == 'left wing'){
        if (player_location == 'Picracko Gallery'){
            if (death_survivability >= 1){
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "You survived death this time, but your death survivability has decreased."
                 death_survivability =  death_survivability - 1
                prompt_input();
    }
            else{
                document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
                restart(10);
    }
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here"
    }
}
    else if (action == 'right wing'){
        if (player_location == 'Picracko Gallery'){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt2();
}
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here"
        }
}

    else if (action == 'bet'){
        bet_print = "Bet." * 1000;
        for (character in bet_print){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += character;
        }
        prompt_input();
    }

    else if (action == 'completed quests'){
        completed_quest_print();
    }
    else if (action == 'clear'){
        clear();
        prompt_input();
    }
    else if (action == 'characters'){
        characters_print();
    }
    else if (action == 'tmdc'){
        if ( tmdc !== true){
             completed_quests.push("...");
             items.push('Emu');
             balance =  balance + (100*10*10*10*10);
             tmdc = true;
             items.push("...");
            prompt_input();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
}
        prompt_input();
}
    else if (action  == 'shark'){
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
        prompt2();
    }
    else if (action  == 'harmless fish'){
        document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
        prompt2();
    }
    else if (action  == 'communism'){
        completed_quests.push("Summon Stalin");
        prompt_input();
    }
    else if (action  == "bowling alley"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            player_location = "Bowling Alley"
            prompt_accomplish2[player_location] = true;
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
    }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command does not work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
    }
    else if (action  == "redacted"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            player_location = "REDACTED, Russia"
            prompt_accomplish2[player_location] = true;
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command does not work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
        }
    else if (action  == "india"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            prompt_accomplish2[player_location] = true;
            player_location = "India"
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command does not work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
        }
    else if (action  == "picracko"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
        }
    else if (action  == "gerbils"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
        }
    else if (action == "shoeburt"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt3();
}
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here."
            prompt_input();
}}
    else if (action == "fuick"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
}
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
}
    else if (action == "eddie"){
        if (player_location == "Payphone"){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "..."
            prompt_input();
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "That command doesn't work here."
            prompt_input();
        }
    }
    else if (action == 'shake'){
        magic_ball();
    }
    else if (action == "painting"){
        picracko_original();
    }
    else if (action == 'h2z456d'){
        if (h2z456d === false){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "Congrats on getting the code! Here is 10000 Dollars, an omletting gun and 4 omlettes."
             balance =  balance + 10000;
             items.push("Omletting Gun");
             items.push("Omlette");
             items.push("Omlette");
             items.push("Omlette");
             items.push("Omlette");
             h2z456d = true;
            prompt_input();
        }
        if (h2z456d === true){
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "You already have used this prompt."
            prompt_input();
        }
        }
     if( acc_check === false){
        var Action_help = "You are unaware of what to do. Try a different command. (Type help for a list of actions)"; 
         document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += Action_help;
        prompt_input();
            }

}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide all relevant code. Stack size error occurs when you call too many functions recursively.

Comment: The code is very long and contains a lot that is not relevant so I'm not sure which bits to include, because most of the functions use innerHTML because that is how I'm appending the Html page with input specific text. I'm trying to find an alternative to innerHTML that I can use repeatedly in many functions without the stack size error.

Comment: I added some of my repeating functions that I thought were relevant.

Comment: That still doesn't look like the culprit. Do you have any loops that trigger innerHTML changes? InnerHTML isn't likely the issue.

Comment: I may have found the loop, I've added it

Comment: A possible way to get this error is that you have a funtion A that calls a function B, which itself calls function A, thus you get a stack A{B{A{B{...}}}}. That can cause a stack size error because no function actually terminates. A better way to do this is to have function A return function B and vice versa, so that some master function M can call M{A->B->A->B->...}, thus you have a limited number of functions on the stack at any time.

Comment: @thatplaneyousaw you are not going to get an answer to your question until you post a question we can answer. That error stems from *infinite recursion*. You shown us tons of irrelevant code, and no relevant code, and there's no way we can possible teach you in the space of a stack overflow answer, much less some comments, *to be able to tell the difference*. I suggest picking a project a little more appropriate for your skill level.

Comment: It is difficult to know which code to show because I only have a vague idea of where the error is. I decided to post the complete prompt_input function which I assume is the cause of the error. It handles user input

Comment: @Jared Smith that comment, regardless of its truthfulness or lack of it, is kind of rude.

Comment: @SydneyY isn't it more rude to just close it with no comment? If I asked an unanswerable question I'd rather be told so than just ignored.

Comment: @Jared Smith sure, but the comment should be about the question, not the person asking it.

Comment: @SydneyY to me, same logic applies: if I bite off more than I can chew, I'd still *rather be told* than just have my question closed as too broad with 4 downvotes and no comments. If you want to tell me I could have phrased it more nicely, well, you're right I probably could have worded it more diplomatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> function prompt_input(){
>   var action = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
>   if (action == ""){
>     prompt_input();
>   }
>   ...
> ```

Here you have an infinite loop.

Nothing before this condition can make the condition change at next call: if the input's `value` is `""`, then it will still be, and your code will continue until it reaches the maximum call stack.

I'm not too sure what you were expecting this recursive call to do, but from a quick look at it, I'd say you just need to early exit when this case happens:

```
function prompt_input(){
  var action = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  if (action == ""){
    return; // early exit
  }
  ...
```